# Probability of defective items, and the probability the first chosen items come from Group A

Tags: probability

I'm still trying to work out how to answer this question.

If Group $A$ has $\frac{1}{100}$ items defective, and Group $B$ has $\frac{1}{200}$ items defective. Overall probability of item being defective is therefore $\frac{3}{200} = 0.015$.

If the first item chosen works (is not defective) what is the probability it came from group $A$?

My thinking on this was just $1 - \frac{1}{100}$. Is that correct?

Secondly, what is the probability the second item works given the first one also works. Should I be applying conditional probability here?

Comment: How did you get $3/200$ as overall probability of being defective? If it is by adding the probabilities $1/100$ and $1/200$ then you are wrong.

Comment: @drhab I should have multiplied them instead?

Comment: No. If $p$ is the probability that the item comes from group $A$ and $1-p$ is the probability that the item comes from group $B$ then the probability of being defective is $p\cdot1/100+(1-p)\cdot1/200$

Comment: so (p *1/100) + (1-p) * (1/200) ?

Comment: If "random" stands for fifty-fifty where it concerns the groups then the probability of being defective is $\frac12\frac1{100}+\frac12\frac1{200}$

Comment: @drhab Yep, I get it now. It's getting late and my brain did a major fart when i first looked at the comment. you're a legend, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both groups are equally large, the a priori probabilities are $P(A) = P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ .Given is (the event $d$ is for defective) $P(d|A) = \frac{1}{100}$ and so $P(\lnot d| A) = \frac{99}{100}$.

So standard Bayesian rules tell us:

$$P(A| \lnot d) = \frac{P(\lnot d|A)P(A)}{P(\lnot d|A)P(A) + P(\lnot d|B)P(B)}$$

which equals $\frac{2\cdot 99}{2\cdot 99+199}$ after simplification (a little less than a half).

Comment: How would I go about calculating the probability of the second item checked being good, given that the first one was? (I am assuming conditional probability :)

Comment: @kitkat1224 further conditioning. You know $P(A|\lnot d)$ and $P(B |\lnot d)$. Now condition P(\lnot d_2)$ in $A$ etc.

Comment: @kitkat1224 so $P(\lnot d_2)= P(\lnot d_2|A)P(A|\lnot d_1) + P(\lnot d_2|B)P(B| \lnot d_1)$

Comment: so that's just giving me the probability that the second watch is not defective, and then I condition it? :) edit. i.e. which rules of probability as I using to work this out?

Comment: Can also approach this problem from the perspective of Probability(two good pieces) / P(first good part) = P(2nd good part | 1st part good)

Comment: I ended up with the answer that the probability of the second watch not being defective given that the first was not, is approx. 99%. I'm not sure if that sounds quite right...